# How to hide DOM content in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

I have a piece of JS code that I am using to hide certain dropdown elements when they are selected.My code works fine on FF,Chrome & IE. But not on safari! How can i go about implementing this to make sure it works on safari as well? Please help, I have tried a few ways but still haven't been able to get it right.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const sectionClass = [".question_1", ".question_2"];
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const selectList = $(sectionClass[i]).find("select");

    for (let i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {
      selectList[i].addEventListener('change', () => disabler())
    }

    function disabler() {

      for (let i = 0; i < selectList.length; i++) {

        selectedValue = selectList[i].value;

        for (let j = 0; j < selectList.length; j++) {

          for (let k = 0; k < selectList[j].length; k++) {
            if (selectList[j][k].value === selectedValue) {
              $(selectList[j][k]).css('display', 'none');
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="session form-1 question_1 word">
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>



<p>DIVIDER</p>



<div class="session form-2 question_2 word">
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `selectList[i].addEventListener('change',disabler)` is simpler but you should delegate. Safari does not support hiding options

Comment: @mplungjan Does this help with the problem I am having or is it just a way of improving my solution?

Comment: Just makes it simpler

Comment: The solution is given in the dupe